# How to merge two arrays of object that can be undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have this object:

```
interface Cart {
    orderPromo?: ProductPromotion[],
    productPromo?: ProductPromotion[],
}
```

Both are the same type, however, they can be undefined, so what is the best and cleanest approach to merging them?

I thought something like these:

```
const promotions: ProductPromotion[] = [...cart.orderPromo, ...cart.productPromo];
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting this error:

```
TS2488: Type 'ProductPromotion[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the properties are optional, `cart.orderPromo` is either an array of `ProductPromotion`, or `undefined` (as indicated by the error message). In the latter case, the use of the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...cart.orderPromo` isn't possible.

You should therefore convert the properties to empty arrays if they are `undefined`, typically with the [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) `??`:

```
const promotions: ProductPromotion[] = [...cart.orderPromo ?? [], ...cart.productPromo ?? []];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that the TS is not sure whether the `cart.orderPromo` or `cart.productPromo` is undefined or not. Since the array can be undefined, you should first check if they exists before merging. By using opt. chaining optr `?.` u can safely access property and with `Nullish Coalescing operator` `??` you can provide a default empty array.

Example:

```
const promotions: ProductPromotion[] = [
  ...(cart.orderPromo ?? []),
  ...(cart.productPromo ?? [])
];
```